# Ajax data not passing looped data

Tags: php, ajax, yii

Am trying to implement a product cart,below is my code

```html
$i=0;
foreach($mycart as $cart){
  $product=AllinOne::ProductDetails($cart[0]);
  $desc='<h5><b>'.CHtml::link($product[2],array('product/details','id'=>$product[0])).'</b></h5>';
  $desc.='<small>'.$product[7].'<br>';
  $subtotal=$product[5]*$cart[1];
  $total=$total+$subtotal;
  echo '<tr><td><span style="float:left; width:40%;">'.CHtml::link('<img class="img-responsive" src="images/home/'.$product[10].'"/>',array('product/details','id'=>$product[0])).'</span><span class=float:right; width:59%;">'.$desc.'</span></td>';
  echo '<td>'.number_format($product[5],2).'</td><td>';
  echo CHtml::NumberField('qty',$cart[1],array('id'=>'qty','min'=>$cart[1],'max'=>$product[17],'style'=>'width:50px;',
    'ajax'=>array(
     'type'=>'POST',
     'update'=>"#subt".$i,//here is the problem,$i takes the //last vaule
     'data'=>array('index'=>$i,'qty'=>'js:this.value'),//'"js:{qty:$('#qty').val()}" js:this.value' 
     'url'=>CController::createUrl('account/twistcart'),
  )));
  echo '</td><td><span id="subt'.$i.'">'.number_format($subtotal).'</span></td><td>'.CHtml::link('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>',array('product/RmvFromCart','i'=>$i),array('class'=>'btn btn-xs btn-danger')).'</td></tr>'; 
  $i++;
 }
```

the problem is in ajax data the $i value takes last value in loop? How do i pass the correct value to ajax data when looping through?

[there when ever i change the quantity it should pass the index and the quantity but it passes the last index to every record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6ge1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Update the loop as below.

```
foreach($mycart as $i=>$cart){

 echo $i; // your  code. $i is the key value here.$i declaration is not required.
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response @Sucharitha,but still facing the same issue,  below is cart array.  Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 993 [1] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 993 [1] => 1 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 992 [1] => 1 ) )

Comment: did u removed $i++ at the end ?

Comment: sure i removed it

Comment: $a=array ( '0' => array('0' => 2, '1' => 1 ),
       '1' => array ( '0' => 993 ,'1' => 1 ) );
foreach($a as $i=>$val){
    echo $i  ."<br>";
}  it will print the array keys. execute this code. u can understand what are the things u missed and what u require exactly.

Comment: ok thanks,but that returns 0 and 1. as expected..and those values are to be passed as ajax data in the variable index but it just passes the last value each time....!!!!

Comment: Yes, here ur key values are o and 1, because of that it is passing 0 and 1. what exactly u require in $i ? show me ur output.

Comment: Its only passing 1 the last value and thats where am confused please check on the image i attached on the post https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6ge1.png

Comment: $a=array ( '0' => array('0' => 2, '1' => 1 ), '1' => array ( '0' => 993 ,'1' => 1 ) );
foreach($a as $i=>$val){
 echo $i.' index &nbsp;';
 echo CHtml::NumberField('qty',1,array('id'=>'qty','min'=>1,'max'=>6,'style'=>'width:50px;',
   'ajax'=>array(
     'type'=>'POST',
     'update'=>"#subt",
     'data'=>array('index'=>$i,'qty'=>'js:this.value'),//'"js:{qty:$('#qty').val()}" js:this.value'
     'url'=>CController::createUrl('account/twistcart'),
   )));
 echo '<br>';
}

Comment: from the image it is not clear. but in your code $i value is printing correctly.

Comment: sure it prints correctly but supprisingly it doesnot pass to ajax as expected,thats the problem facing...                                                   ajax'=>array(
     'type'=>'POST',
     'update'=>"#subt".$i,//here is the problem,$i takes the //last vaule
     'data'=>array('index'=>$i,'qty'=>'js:this.value'),//'"js:{qty:$('#qty').val()}" js:this.value' 
     'url'=>CController::createUrl('account/twistcart'),
  )

Comment: here the problem is not with the ajax. your updating('update'=>"#subt".$i)  a filed by its id. so to update that their should be that filed exists.

Comment: please refer to this 
<?php 
$a=array ( '0' => array('0' => 2, '1' => 1 ), '1' => array ( '0' => 993 ,'1' => 1 ) ); foreach($a as $i=>$val){ echo $i.' index &nbsp;'; echo CHtml::NumberField('qty',1,array('id'=>'qty','min'=>1,'max'=‌​>6,'style'=>'width:5‌​0px;', 'ajax'=>array( 'type'=>'POST', 'update'=>"#subt", 'data'=>array('index'=>$i,'qty'=>'js:this.value'),//'"j‌​s:{qty:$('#qty').val‌​()}" js:this.value' 'url'=>CController::createUrl('account/twistcart'), ))); echo '<br>'; }.   echo '<span id="subt">display here</span>'; ?>

Comment: Thanks very much..@sucharitha,for ur time,i did a silly mistake thats why i was facing that problem on  'id'=>'qty', since they had the same id..,solution is to have different id eg 'id'=>'qty'.$i,  or remove id's